# Ordenando uma ListView por ordem alfabética no vb 6

Tags: visual-basic-6, listview

Eu tenho duas listas A e B, os dados da lista A são exportados do BD, esses já trago ordenados alfabeticamente para a lista. A partir desta lista eu adiciono dados na outra lista (lista B), os dados que são inseridos na lista B, ficam ordenados de acordo com a ordem de inserção.

Gostaria de saber como faço para ordenar uma ListView por ordem alfabética.

Answer (score 3):

Sete isto ao construir a `ListView`:

```
minhaListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
```